# box muller equations returning NA values

Tags: r

```
  #generating 100 uniformly distributed numbers
  u1 <- runif(100,0,1)
  u2 <- runif(100,0,1)
  

  x1 <- function(x, y) {
    return(sqrt(-2 * log(x) * cos(2 * pi * y)))
  }
  x2 <- function(x, y) {
    return(sqrt(-2 * log(x) * sin(2 * pi * y)))
  }
  #applying x1
  x1_vals <- mapply(x1, u1, u2)
  #applying x2
  x2_vals <- mapply(x2, u1, u2)
```

Hi I want to write a box muller function, this is part of my attempt above, I'm trying to avoid using loops as much as possible(for loops especially)
However, I keep getting NA values for my x1/x2 functions. I can't figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Square roots of negative numbers are ... what? Think about it.

Comment: The parenthesis close right after `log(.)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas The code ran for me. He's getting NA's because half of his arguments to sqrt are negative. There's also the concern that he's using `mapply` when the function is already vectorized and doesn't need to havean mapply wrapper.

Comment: @IRTFM The code runs but that's not the Box-Muller formula, the BM formula multiplies the sqrt of -2*log(x) by expressions in sin and cos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Box-Muller formula corrected.

```r
x1 <- function(x, y) sqrt(-2 * log(x)) * cos(2 * pi * y)
x2 <- function(x, y) sqrt(-2 * log(x)) * sin(2 * pi * y)

u1 <- runif(1000,0,1)
u2 <- runif(1000,0,1)

# applying x1
x1_vals <- x1(u1, u2)
all(is.finite(x1_vals))
#> [1] TRUE

# applying x2
x2_vals <- x2(u1, u2)
all(is.finite(x2_vals))
#> [1] TRUE

old_par <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
hist(x1_vals, freq = FALSE)
curve(dnorm, from = -4, to = 4, add = TRUE)
hist(x2_vals, freq = FALSE)
curve(dnorm, from = -4, to = 4, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
par(old_par)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Those functions are already vectorized. Don't need to wrap mapply around them. Just give the two vectors to `x1` and `x2`

```
x1(u1,u2)
  [1]       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN 0.3088330
  [6]       NaN 0.7866889       NaN       NaN 1.7102801
 [11] 2.1886770       NaN 1.5473627 1.0644378 0.8499208
snipped remaining 100 values
```

Vectorization is a feature of the R language. If the expressions in the function body can all take vectors and return vectors of equal length then no loop wrapper is needed.

You are getting NA's because the domain of the arguments to `sin` and `cos` are causing both positive and negative values to be given to `sqrt`.