# How do I replace the for loop with something else

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vectorization, apply

I have a for loop as shown below. How do I replace the for loop with something else (ie apply, lapply)?

```
f <- function(n) {
  for (i in 1:n) {
     U1 <- runif(1)
     U2 <- runif(1)
     X1 <- sqrt(-2*log(U1))*cos(2*pi*U2)
     X2 <- sqrt(-2*log(U1))*sin(2*pi*U2)
     samp1[i] = X1
     samp2[i] = X2
  }
  }
```

Comment: All the functions being used are vectorized so you don't need any kind of iterative approach, just e.g., `n <- 10; sqrt(-2*log(runif(n)))*cos(2*pi*runif(n))`.

Comment: but that assumes that my n is 10 right? What about for a generic case, before n is set as a specific number. I have edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: You can set `n` to any number you like. You can even wrap the code in a function and pass `n` as a parameter. You need to define `n` somewhere with your `for` loop too or you'll get an error.

Comment: I don't follow your concern.  Irrespective of the approach, the length of the output needs to be determined by setting `n` to some value.

Comment: but the example code give by Sacramento will only calculate  sqrt(-2*log(runif(n)))*cos(2*pi*runif(n)) for n = 10 no? But I would like to calculate  sqrt(-2*log(runif(n)))*cos(2*pi*runif(n)) for n=1,2,3,4,...,n

Comment: See the comments and my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73876031/box-muller-equations-returning-na-values/). R is vectorized, there is not need for a loop.

Comment: oohhhh. Thank you! But what about in samp1[i] and samp2[I]?

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments, exploit vectorization. Moreover, reduce function calls.

```
f <- \(n) {
  g <- \() {
    U <- runif(2)
    term1 <- sqrt(-2*log(U[1]))
    term1*c(cos(2*pi*U[2]), sin(2*pi*U[2]))
  }
  t(replicate(n, g()))
}

set.seed(42)
f(5)
#            [,1]       [,2]
# [1,]  0.3894476 -0.1625330
# [2,]  0.7660039 -1.3841204
# [3,] -0.9351026 -0.1127383
# [4,]  0.5183431  0.5854679
# [5,] -0.2553665 -0.8803147
```